# В Android Studio в редакторе макетов пропало большинство атрибутов - напр, цвет текста, выравнивание. Их нет даже в списке Все атрибуты

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Не понял, с какого момента это случилось.

Атрибуты повляются в списке только, если их добавить вручную через редактирование XML.

Вот все атрибуты у `TextView`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вернуть всё на место?

Answer (score 0):

Только что столкнулся с данной проблемой при создании проекта на 33 sdk.(если откатить до 32, то атрибуты возвращаются)

**Решение:** Обновить android studio до последней версии(Electric Eel в моем случае) и проблема пропала.